# Как сделать доступ по хостам в squid?

Tags: linux, squid, acl

Есть домен site.ru. И куча приписанных к серверу поддоменов (на самом деле * CNAME site.ru). Необходимо, чтобы при доступе к sub1.site.ru человек получал ip1, при sub2 - ip2 итд.

Т.е. примерно вот так:

```
http_port ip2.site.ru:8085 name=nip2 
http_port ip3.site.ru:8085 name=nip3

acl ip2 myip ip2.site.ru
acl ip3 myip ip3.site.ru

tcp_outgoing_address <ip2> ip2 
tcp_outgoing_address <ip3> ip3 
tcp_outgoing_address <default ip>
```

Но проблема в том, что он берет первое правило с ip2 и применяет его. Видимо потому, что он резолвит хост к ip-адресу (а он у всех поддоменов один).

Если делать на уровне портов, то всё работает:

```
http_port 8085 name=port2 
http_port 8086 name=port3

acl ip2 myportname port2 
acl ip3 myportname port3 

tcp_outgoing_address <ip2> ip2 
tcp_outgoing_address <ip3> ip3 
tcp_outgoing_address <default ip>
```

Но мне необходим именно доступ по различным доменам. Планируется большое количество хостов и вручную приписывать A-записи — не вариант.